# Python: Validate if MX Record(s) of Domain Name have active inbox. Check mx records, validate email

Tags: python, email, networking, dns, mx-record

I need to validate the existence of an inbox related to the MX records found in the DNS zone/record of a domain name. After I retrieve all the MXs with the `dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')` I sort then based on priority and I loop with the following function and test them one by one to see if they have active. After I get all the MXs I pass them to the `check_mailbox()` one by one. The `mx_record` is the variable with the MX value exmp. mx.something.com. And the `mail` variable, the second parameter, is the actual email I am testing.

my current function:

```
def check_mailbox(mx_record, mail):
    code = ""

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=300)
        server.set_debuglevel(0)  # 1 for all data show
        server.connect(mx_record['mx'])  # Starting the communication 
        server.helo(server.local_hostname)
        server.mail("from@address.sample")
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(mail))  # Test the mailbox
        server.quit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        code = "error"
    finally:
        if code == 250 or code == 251:
            return {'code': code, 'message': message}
        else:
            return False
```

In my current function as I said I test individually all MXs. Of course depending on network it can have some delays.

- I need to know is there a faster way I can perform this check?
- Is there another (completely other) way I can perform this validation?
- Would it be better if I don't do the server.quit() after each check
  but open it, keep it open and close it after all checks are done?

thank you in advance.

---

any additional information you need just ask me. Before I go to this phase I have an logic follow up like this:
*run() -> check(email) -> validator() -> checkEmailStructure() -> checkDomainAlive() -> checkHasMXs() -> loop to oder -> loop with check_mailbox()*

this way I make sure if structure is bad, end validation. If, domain is dead end validation. And only if structure OK, domain OK and has MXs then loop to check. Also in the last loop if one of the MXs returns 250 or 251 I stop testing because at least one works! I order in terms of priority.

any suggestions are welcomed! The need here is to optimize and assure the goal.

Comment: What's the point of testing *all* of the MX servers for the mailbox? They should all represent *one* logical mail server, and should all have the same set of mailboxes. Thus you should only proceed to a secondary server if the first one fails to connect.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I do stop if one return 250 or 251 :) I just updated. I also check in order of priority after ordering them so till here all good

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know is there a faster way I can perform this check?

Some mail servers allow you to send all commands at once (helo, mail, rect, quit) before waiting for each response. However only some mail servers support this, and it's usually the fast mail servers anyway (like Google), so there's not much benefit from it.

> Is there another (completely other) way I can perform this validation?

No that I know of. Some mail servers have a `vrfy` command, but most don't.

> Would it be better if I don't do the server.quit() after each check
> but open it, keep it open and close it after all checks are done?

Yes, this would make things much faster. You might need to use the `RSET` command in-between checks, not sure though.

Worth noting too that even if the `rcpt` command is successful, there's still no guarantee that the email address works. Yahoo/Verizon/AOL for example won't give an error until after the `data` command for example.